# Boot from USB iBook G4 Power PC

Tags: usb, startup, books, powerpc

I recently got an old iBook G4 (as many of you might have noticed with all of my recent questions :D) and I wanted to install Ubuntu via USB (the iso doesn't fit on a CD and the iBook doesn't read DVDs, I've tried).

So I went a-searching the internet for ways to do this.

I started off trying to boot from the USB stick via holding down <kbd>option</kbd> after the chime, but that just listed the Macintosh HD. So I went on searching and came across this: http://ben-collins.blogspot.com/2010/08/booting-your-ibook-g4-from-usb-stick.html and tried it multiple times, but all failed (I believe the iBook wasn't recognizing the USB stick, as nothing came up when I ran `dev usb0` and then `ls`.)

I then read this question: [How do I make my 1.5 GHz PowerBook G4 boot from a USB stick?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11128/how-do-i-make-my-1-5-ghz-powerbook-g4-boot-from-a-usb-stick), but that didn't work, even when I swapped out the suffix `\\yaboot` for `\\tdxi`. Sadly, nothing is working!

Does anyone know of any workarounds or something I can do to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

I know this old, but I just solved this problem, and I had found this question while searching for an answer.

In my case, 2005 iBook wouldn't recognise the 10.5 install DVD. I imaged the DVD to an 8GB usb stick in Disk Utility. I did format the USB stick as `Apple Partition Map` first in case that makes a difference.

It wouldn't boot from the USB when holding down <kbd>option</kbd> or <kbd>C</kbd> though I could get a menu.

I booted to open firmware by booting with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
then I ran the following command:
`boot usb0/disk@1:3,\\:tbxi`

It booted into the installer and everything worked as expected.