# How to update 10.4.6 to 10.4.11 on PowerPC?

Tags: macos, software-update, powerpc

So, my father randomly unearthed an old iBook G4 from somewhere and wanted me to make the Internet working. It has Safari and Internet Explorer preinstalled, but they both come from more than a decade ago and have troubles with modern HTML5 and certificates CAs. Thus I decided to install Firefox fork named "TenFourFox", but it can only launch from operation system older than 10.4.11. I have 10.4.6.

So, Apple website has a lot of dead links, but I managed to find a working cumulative update 10.4.* → 10.4.11 [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL170). The problem is – it just won't install.

[image: You cannot install the update onto this volume. It does not meet the requirements for update. 43.8GB of 55.8GB free. 573MB required.]

Some techincal info: OS has build 8I127, CPU is 1.33GHz PowerPC (ppc7450), has 512MB RAM. Don't know what the disk is, I cannot get `lsblk` or something running. :/ 
`diskutil info disk0s3` prints only its UUID and HFS+, but nothing more of importance. To me, at least.

Rebooting the PC did not help.

➥ Does anyone remember how they dealt with installing the update in the past or knows any other browser that will show modern sites?

**UPD:** diskutil output:

```
>> diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                   type name               size      identifier
   0: Apple_partition_scheme                    *55.9 GB  disk0
   1:    Apple_partition_map                    31.5 KB   disk0s1
   2:              Apple_HFS Macintosh HD       55.8 GB   disk0s3
```

```
>> diskutil info disk0
   Device Node:        /dev/disk0
   Device Identifier:  disk0
   Mount Point:        
   Volume Name:        

   Partition Type:     Apple_partition_scheme
   Bootable:           Not bootable
   Media Type:         Generic
   Protocol:           ATA
   SMART Status:       Verified

   Total Size:         55.9 GB
   Free Space:         0.0 B

   Read Only:          No
   Ejectable:          No
   OS 9 Drivers:       No
   Low Level Format:   Not Supported
```

```
>> diskutil info disk0s1
   Device Node:        /dev/disk0s1
   Device Identifier:  disk0s1
   Mount Point:        
   Volume Name:        

   Partition Type:     Apple_partition_map
   Bootable:           Not bootable
   Media Type:         Generic
   Protocol:           ATA
   SMART Status:       Verified

   Total Size:         31.5 KB
   Free Space:         0.0 B

   Read Only:          Yes
   Ejectable:          No
```

```
>> diskutil info disk0s3
   Device Node:        /dev/disk0s3
   Device Identifier:  disk0s3
   Mount Point:        /
   Volume Name:        Macintosh HD

   File System:        Journaled HFS+
                       Journal size 8192 k at offset 0x1c1000
   Owners:             Enabled
   Partition Type:     Apple_HFS
   Bootable:           Is bootable
   Media Type:         Generic
   Protocol:           ATA
   SMART Status:       Verified
   UUID:               03AB652C-D223-3FA3-AABF-C0684FDB1EEB

   Total Size:         55.8 GB
   Free Space:         43.8 GB

   Read Only:          No
   Ejectable:          No
```

**UPD2:** There could be something with partition schemes, as per [this site](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c090fe/you-cannot-install-mac-os-x-on-this-volume-how-to-resolve/). However, [this one](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ajxz) says

> Intel Macs require the `GUID Partition Table` for their startup disks, while PowerPC Macs use `Apple Partition Map`, so my case looks ok from this perspective.
>   Unfortunately, this MacOS cannot repartition the volume it's currently running from. Who could guess. :D

Well, I'll try to find an Opera 10.6 distributable for PowerPCs and postpone this task until I have a bootable CD-disk. (Was mentioned in help in Disk Utilities as a way to manipulate the sole hdd.)

Comment: Can you add the output of `diskutil info disk0` and `diskutil list disk0`? I don't think it's a disk problem though, it's probably more that the OS installed on the volume doesn't allow updating (for yet to be determined reasons)

Comment: @nohillside, updated the post. I'll try to look into "volumes that do not allow updating", thanks.

Comment: I saw a thread somewhere once that indicated you need one or more updates **between** 10.4.6 and 10.4.11. Potentially 10.4.7, 10.4.8, etc.

Comment: @SteveChambers Hmm. The documentation states `The combo update for PowerPC-based Macs updates Mac OS X (PowerPC) 10.4, 10.4.1, 10.4.2, 10.4.3, 10.4.4, 10.4.5, 10.4.6, 10.4.7, 10.4.8, 10.4.9, or 10.4.10 to 10.4.11.`. There are links to these delta updates, but it seems Apple long moved all its downloadable files from docs.info.apple.com to support.apple.com and another urls. I tried bruteforcing https://support.apple.com/kb/DL$number_here$, but found only 10.4.6 and 10.4.8 updates so far. 10.4.7 is missing. :/

Comment: I also tried looking here: https://support.apple.com/downloads/10.4.7%2520PPC. There's also no mentions of 10.4.7. Probably it never existed and I should try installing 10.4.8 over 10.4.6...

Comment: I have found that documentation is written by people who have no connection with the people that produce the actual software. So you are best served by the plate of spaghetti against the wall method, whereby you try everything even remotely possible in the hopes that something will work. Once you have found that hold onto the software for much longer than you think it would be useful... says the man with the Mac OS 10.0.0 original install disks...

Comment: It is possible that "This volume does not meet the requirements for this update" is a red herring (not an accurate description of the true cause of the problem). Two ideas... 1. See if you can find more detail in the logs about what problem the installer is encountering. It'll log this at some point in time between you starting the installer and arriving at the point shown in your screenshot. Should be visible somewhere in /Applications/Utilities/Console.app.

Comment: 2. Try changing the machine's date back to 2008, say (after the release of 10.4, but not too far after). Some Apple installers contain a dated security certificate, and refuse to run (with a misleading error) if the difference between the machine date and the date in the certificate is too large. 10.4 may be before they added that certificate to installers, though, but worth a quick try.

Comment: Also, re: "other browser that will show modern sites". [TenFourFox's FAQ](https://github.com/classilla/tenfourfox/wiki/AAATheFAQ#i-tried-to-download-tenfourfox-from-sourceforge-and-i-got-a-security-error) links to [Opera 10.63](http://www.oldapps.com/mac/opera.php?old_opera=39), saying "This version of Opera was previously the only known browser for Power Macs to support TLS 1.2 and runs on 10.4 and 10.5". Worth a try?

Comment: @Ashley, thanks for pointing me to logs. There were nothing useful, but it directed my steps towards terminal. Changing machine date back to 2008 did not help, but also did not broke anything, as it seems. About browsers – well, I've been using Opera 12.16 for a long time until some sites were displaying broken and until they've released 12.17 to fight security issues I don't remember (probably expiring root certificates and SSL/TLS things). So, I don't think it will do any better on http sites than Safari 2.0.3. Still, I'll treat it as plan C if everything goes wrong. Thanks. :D

Comment: Bother. Ok, another idea. I think that machine can run 10.5... 1.33GHz is either iBook G4 (Late 2004) or Mid 2005 and either can run 10.5 (all according to Mactracker). How do you feel about trying to upgrade to that?

Comment: @Ashley, Oh, I don't particularly care about what OS version will be on that macbook, and neither my father cares, I suppose. I haven't thought about getting an higher OS version due to the fact this is the first Apple device I've been working so thoroughly with and because I wanted to sweat little blood and simply update the OS. Now, if I am going to reinstall it, there is a choice what to install, right? And I can see, there is a way to install it via USB ([link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/115120)), without any need for burning discs or finding original ones. Cool, thanks! :D

Comment: Excellent. It's a bit of a change in direction, but might work. I think you will need a 10.5 install DVD, or an image of one, though. Be careful of images of disks on the Internet... it's possible they aren't what they say they are. (Although I mention that as a theoretical possibility - I haven't heard of problems like that with 10.5 in reality, but good to be cautious.) Re choices during reinstall - yes, there are a few, but perhaps not as many as you might expect. There's a screenshot of the options (but for 10.6) here: https://www.macworld.com/article/1142454/install-snow-leopard.html

Comment: Oh and make sure anything important on the machine is backed up before starting to wrestle with reinstalling, just in case...