# PowerBook G4 not booting from USB installer

Tags: usb, powerbook

When I'm trying to boot my PowerBook G4 12" (A1104) from a Panther/Tiger/Leopard install USB, it tries to boot, displays the Apple Logo but then the x as seen on the picture.
What should I do?[image: Comes up after the Apple Logo when booting from install usb]

Comment: Get a Tiger or Leopard DVD. Or, get (find) the original DVD for that Mac, which should have OS X 10.3.7 (Panther). Or, you could try the first [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11128/how-do-i-make-my-1-5-ghz-powerbook-g4-boot-from-a-usb-stick?rq=1) I see in the Related column.